# Read html in cmd file and get the img tag

Tags: html, regex, batch-file

I have to read a html file in a cmd file. There I have to look for the img tag and in this tag a have to get the string of the src. How can I handle that?

I tried to read line by line and there try to get known if there's the img tag inside with this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (./mypage.htm) do (

echo %%a| findstr /r "<img.*src.*/>">nul
    if errorlevel 0 (
        echo %%a
    )
)
```

But with this it displayed all lines and also some error messages like: "can not find file" or "syntax error"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of greedy quantifier try to use lazy `.*?` and also escape slash `\/`: `<img.*src.*?\/>`

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be easier if Windows included more robust command-line regexp interpreters.  `findstr` is fine for providing a boolean match / no match or returning the full line containing the match, but can't really compete with the flexibility of `sed` or `grep -o` for matching and returning only the matching part of that line.

What I would do is use Windows Scripting Host (VBScript / JScript) for the more robust regexp and string manipulation tools available there.  Here's an example .bat / JScript hybrid:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "htmlfile=test.html"

rem // invoke hybrid JScript code
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%htmlfile%"') do (
    rem // do stuff with %%I
    echo found: %%I
)

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end
// end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    html = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    images = html.ReadAll().replace(/\r?\n/g, '').match(/img[^>]+?src=(['"]).+?(?=\1)/ig);

html.Close();
WSH.Echo(images.join('\n').replace(/img[^>]+?src=['"]/ig,''));
```

This should successfully match

```
<img src="typical.jpg">

<img class="noclick" src="class/included.png" />

<img style="border: 0"
src="tag/has/line/break.gif">

<img src="http://apostrophe/in/source's name.jpg">

<img src='single-quoted.jpg' />
```

... which would be difficult even for `sed` or `grep`.

---

If you've got a particularly stubborn HTML document that eludes regexp scraping, you could invoke Internet Explorer as a COM object to parse the `<img>` tags as DOM nodes.  This would be beneficial if you're trying to scrape a page whose images are populated dynamically through JavaScript or CSS pseudo elements.  This invocation of IE is much *much* slower, but it's a failsafe.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "htmlfile=test.html"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%htmlfile%"') do (
    rem // do stuff with %%I
    echo %%I
)

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end
// end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    IE = WSH.CreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application'),
    htmlfile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WSH.Arguments(0));

IE.Visible = 0;
IE.Navigate('file:///' + htmlfile.replace(/\\/g, '/'));
while (IE.Busy || IE.ReadyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(25);

var images = IE.document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) WSH.Echo(images[i].src);

IE.Quit();
```